# Angular 9 - cookie been saved on wrong domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cookies, angular9

My client side and server side run on different domains. 
and when I do a login to the server I save the cookie on the response.
but Angular save that cookie only for the client-side domain for some reason...

Server:

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const userData = req.body;
  User.findOne(userData).then(data => {
    if (data) {
      const token = jwt.sign(userData, process.env.SECRET);
      res.cookie("token", token);
      res.send();
    } else {
      res.status(401).send("Login Failed");
    }
  });
});
```

My client runs on localhost:4200
and my server on localhost:3000
(I tried it from completely different domains and still the same issue)

[image]

Also tried using ngx-cookie-service, but it's also only working with the client domain

Comment: It's not angular's fault , the browser will place the cookie path according to the response headers and cookie details , it's a backend issue .

Comment: all i did is add the cookie to the response, so are you saying that because the response destination is the client side it will save the cookie there?

Comment: update ngx-cookie-service version 3.0.0 or above will solve the issue i was also facing the same issue

Comment: https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your cookie for particular domain like this by passing domain into set function

Cookie is stored for localhost so port is not concern here.

```
this.cookieService.set(cookieName, value, expiry, '/','localhost');
```

Get cookie

```
this.cookieService.get(cookieName);
```

Comment: I tried it, it did save the cookie for that domain BUT it only works if I'm opening a new tab (i checked and it uses the cookie with the token), but when Angular is trying to go to that domain it doesn't add the cookie to the headers and I'm getting 401 Unauthorized